# Dynamic Nested Loops (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, nested

Hello I am looking for a way to write this C++ Code in a general way, so that if a want 20 columns I will not have to write 20 for loops:

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++) {
    for(int j=i; j<6; j++) {
        for(int k=j; k<6; k++) {
            for(int m=k; m<6; m++) {
                std::cout << i << j << k << m << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is important that my numbers follow a >= Order. 
I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: std::slice? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/slice/

Comment: Is there a practical use, or just curious?  6^20 is a pretty big number.

Comment: @Yakk the practical use is that my numbers stand for indices and i need to list them in such a way in order to work with them. Furthermore I just used the number 20 as an extreme example. Since I want to follow a >= order the order of my numbers would be 177,100 (=binomial(25,6))

Comment: @cdrjohn good point.  Improved my answer so it doesn't do 6^20 steps to find those 177100 elements.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

This recursive function should work:

```
#include <iostream>

bool inc( int *indexes, int limit, int n )
{
    if( ++indexes[n] < limit )
        return true;
    if( n == 0 ) return false;
    if( inc( indexes, limit, n-1 ) ) {
        indexes[n] = indexes[n-1];
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

int main()
{
    const size_t N=3;
    int indexes[N];
    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) indexes[i] = 1;

    do {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) std::cout << indexes[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while( inc( indexes, 6, N-1 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/429d346ff500a165)

Comment: Thanks for your code Slava. This will be the option that I will be using. I had thought myself of recursion, but my attempts were really appalling.

Answer (score 1):

The design here is simple.  We take a `std::vector` each containing a dimension count and a `std::vector` containing a current index at each dimension.

`advance` advances the current bundle of dimension indexes by `amt` (default 1).

```
void advance( std::vector<size_t>& indexes, std::vector<size_t> const& counts, size_t amt=1 ) {
  if (indexes.size() < counts.size())
    indexes.resize(counts.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < counts.size(); ++i ) {
    indexes[i]+=amt;
    if (indexes[i] < counts[i])
      return;
    assert(counts[i]!=0);
    amt = indexes[i]/counts[i];
    indexes[i] = indexes[i]%counts[i];
  }
  // past the end, don't advance:
  indexes = counts;
}
```

which gives us an advance function for generic n dimensional coordinates.

Next, a filter that tests the restriction you want:

```
bool vector_ascending( std::vector<size_t> const& v ) {
  for (size_t i = 1; (i < v.size()); ++i) {
    if (v[i-1] < v[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

then a `for` loop that uses the above:

```
void print_a_lot( std::vector<size_t> counts ) {
  for( std::vector<size_t> v(counts.size()); v < counts; advance(v,counts)) {
    // check validity
    if (!vector_ascending(v))
      continue;
    for (size_t x : v)
      std::cout << (x+1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2afad3e12062e77).

No recursion needed.

The downside to the above is that it generates 6^20 elements, and then filters.  We don't want to make that many elements.

```
void advance( std::vector<size_t>& indexes, std::vector<size_t> const& counts, size_t amt=1 ) {
  if (indexes.size() < counts.size())
    indexes.resize(counts.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < counts.size(); ++i ) {
    indexes[i]+=amt;
    if (indexes[i] < counts[i])
    {
      size_t min = indexes[i];
      // enforce <= ordering:
      for (size_t j = i+i; j < counts.size(); ++j) {
        if (indexes[j]<min)
          indexes[j]=min;
        else
          break; // other elements already follow <= transitively
      }
      assert(vector_ascending(indexes));
      return;
    }
    assert(counts[i]!=0);
    amt = indexes[i]/counts[i];
    indexes[i] = indexes[i]%counts[i];
  }
  // past the end, don't advance:
  indexes = counts;
}
```

which should do it without the `vector_ascending` check in the previous version.  (I left the assert in to do testing).

Comment: your advance does not take into account his ">=" requirement

Comment: @tobi303 yep.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This function works for me, but do not call it with 20 if you want it to finish.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<std::list<int>> fun (std::list<std::list<int>> inputlist, int counter)
{
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        return inputlist;
    }
    else
    {
        std::list<std::list<int>> outputlist;
        for(std::list<int> oldlist : inputlist)
        {
            for(int i = 1; i<6; i++)
            {
                std::list<int> newlist = oldlist;
                newlist.push_back(i);
                outputlist.push_back(newlist);
            }
        }
        return fun(outputlist, counter - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> somelist;
    std::list<std::list<int>> listlist;
    listlist.push_back(somelist);
    std::list<std::list<int>> manynumbers = fun (listlist,5);
    for (std::list<int> somenumbers : manynumbers)
    {
        for(int k : somenumbers)
        {
            std::cout<<k;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you also dont take into account his ">=" requirement

Comment: @tobi303 ah, missed that.

Comment: if follow a >= order means that the small numbers are printed first, my function does that

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I tried it and it worked. I will not be running it with 20 columns, I just used that number to state that I would like to have the number of columns variable.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you need the function for anything where performance might become an issue (or you actually want to call it with 20) some of the other solutions are better though. (e.g. Slava's function  worked with N=20 on my PC)

Answer (score 0):

Same with Processing (java) here :

```
void loopFunction(int targetLevel, int actualLevel, int min, int max, String prefix){
  /*
    targetLevel is the wanted level (20 in your case)
    actualLevel starts from 1
    min starts from 1
    max is the max number displayed (6 in your case)
    prefix starts from blank
    see usage bellow (in setup function)
  */
  for(int m=min; m<max; m++) {
    if(targetLevel==actualLevel)
    {
      println(prefix+ " " + m);
    }
    else
    {
      loopFunction(targetLevel, actualLevel+1,m,max,prefix+ " " + m);
    }
  }
}

void setup(){

  loopFunction(10,1,1,6,"");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not the fastest in writing answer... when I started there was no other answer. Anyhow, here is my version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Multiindex {
    public:
        typedef std::vector<int> Index;
        Multiindex(int dims,int size) : 
             dims(dims),size(size),index(Index(dims,0)){}
        void next(){
            int j=dims-1;
            while (nextAt(j) && j >= 0){j--;}
        }
        Index index;
        bool hasNext(){return !(index[0]==size-1);}
    private:
        bool nextAt(int j){
            index[j] = index[j]+1;
            bool overflow = (index[j]==size);
            if (!overflow && j < dims-1){std::fill(index.begin() + j + 1,index.end(),index[j]);}
            return overflow;
        }
    int dims;
    int size;
};

int main() {
   Multiindex m(4,6);
   while (m.hasNext()){
       cout << m.index[0] << m.index[1] << m.index[2] << m.index[3] << endl;
       m.next();
   }
   cout << m.index[0] << m.index[1] << m.index[2] << m.index[3] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```